# Your account already has a valid iOS Development certificate

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I borrowed an iPad mini (MF432C/A) iOS 8.0.2 from another department in my company working on a **different** iOS app and tried to build my application.

I received the following error when attempting to build on it via Xcode Version 6.4 (6E35b)

> **Failed to code sign ----.**
>
> None of the valid provisioning profiles include the devices: 725
> product dev iPad mini.
>
> Xcode can attempt to fix this issue.

[image]

After clicking Fix Issue which has been doing a decent job of auto-provisioning unknown devices lately I get the following message:

> **Your account already has a valid iOS Development certificate**
>
> You have a valid iOS Development certificate in the Member Center, but
> it is not installed locally. If your signing identity is installed on
> another Mac, you can export a developer profile on that Mac and import
> it on this Mac. You can also revoke your current certificate and
> request a new one.

[image]

From the relevant [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html) it looks like I'm missing the correct signing identity to build my app on this device. The issue is that this is likely the signing identity of the developers of the other application. Is there a way to bypass this error and provision the device for my own application?

**Edit:** Under the activity log I see the following two Code Signing errors:

> Check dependencies
>
> Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: None of the
> valid provisioning profiles include the devices: 725 product dev iPad
> mini
>
> CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type
> 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.4'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> You need to install the public and private keys associated with the
>   development profile onto the Mac you are using. They can be found in
>   the Keychain application, and simply transferred over. You can revoke
>   and request a new one, but then your device may not run the app from
>   your work computer and you would have to rinse and repeat.

If you've already done this and are still experiencing issues, try registering the device manually under Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles in the member centre and then refresh the account under Xcode > preferences > accounts > [accountname]

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned. A key component here is the department I borrowed it from is working on a different iOS app. That's why I don't want their development profile. I need to use my own but preferably without needing to remove them from the device.

Comment: @alexgophermix So, are you using your own developer account, or someone's else? This error has nothing to do with the device and will not affect it.

Comment: @mifki I'm using my own developer account and haven't experienced this issue on other devices before. Already provisioned devices are still working normally

Comment: @mifki not sure why it wasn't resolving properly through Xcode but after registering the device manually under Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles in the member centre and refreshing the account under Xcode > preferences > accounts > [accountname] it is building properly. Thanks for your help